Problem after data migration from MySQL to Supabase
so basically I had a RDS running with a DB and wanted to switch it to Postgres with Supabase, so I followed the official documentation and managed to get it all done.
The problem begins when im trying to fetch that data from a simple React app. IDK why but everytime I tried to consume the migrated tables I got:
401: "permission denied for table x"

First I moved all tables to public scheme, then disabled RLS to all of them but still nothing worked.
But querying any other table created from Supabase was ok? Not sure what else I have to configure.
Sorry if im missing obvious things, im new to supabase and postgres

Pretty straightforward whatever user(role) you are using to query the tables does not have permissions on those tables. This is does not involve RLS as the error is on the table itself not a given row. Verify what user you are using and what permissions they have.
